# vim does not set undodir properly

Tags: vim

My `.vimrc` file you can find at [GitHub](https://github.com/rungokarol/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc)

There are two lines:

```
" Setup persistent undo
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
```

When I run `so ~/.vimrc manualy` then the `undodir` variable is setted properly to `~/.vim/undodir` but after opening vim session it is equal to `.undodir` and vim creates this folder in my working copy.

I run `vim -D` but found nothing interesting:
after set the path was `~/.vim/undodir` but in the end it was resetted to default.

Comment: What does `:verbose set undodir?` tell you?

Comment: I've already solved this problem. VimWorkspace plugin override this variable